# Confusion regarding Biased Clipper Circuit

Tags: voltage-clipping

[image: Clipper Circuit]

When the voltage is lower then the biased voltage its appear in Output Voltage, But just when the voltage get larger than Bias Voltage (Vb) the Diode start Conducting and its acts as SHORT and the voltage gets clipped.

But the thing that confuses me is that i learnt that Short makes potential Difference zero so when the diode was conductiong its act as short instead of clipped voltage which is appearing at output it must be zero voltage, right ?

Comment: It would be zero volts across the diode and not zero volts to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this make sense to you: -

[image]

Or do you need more clarification?

*Note- Ideal diode assumed*

Comment: in second case all the extra "Vin" voltage is getting dropped across Series Resistor "R" ?

Comment: @fpsshubham - correct.

Answer (score 1):

---

> But the thing that confuses me is that i learnt that Short makes
>   potential Difference zero so when the diode was conductiong its act as
>   short instead of clipped voltage which is appearing at output it must
>   be zero voltage, right ?

---

What you are saying is entirely correct : when the diode conducts it acts as a short (ideal diode) and  has zero volts across it terminals. However, the non-ideal diode do have some voltage drop , which is 0.7 in your example. So, apply KVL to the loop, when the diode is conducting : the output voltage = Vb + Vdiode = Vb + 0.7

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine the diode as a switch that turns on then V_anode > V_cathode and off when V_anode < V_cathode. A more accurate model, when the diode is conducting, is the following

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0cxEv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, when Vin < Vd+V_on, the diode is off (not conducting) hence Vin appears at Vout. When Vin > Vd + V_on, the diode is on and the current passes through R, V_on, Vd and returns to the source. In the latter case, Vout is the voltage across the diode and Vd, so it's Vd + V_on